# Php Array Elements difference

Tags: php, arrays

There two arrays:

```
Array1 ( 
[309] => "100"
[310] => "200"
[311] => "400"
)

Array2 ( 
[309] => "1"
[310] => "2"
[311] => "4"
)
```

How to get resulted array with difference of elements from arrays? i.e:

```
Array3 ( 
    [309] => "99"
    [310] => "198"
    [311] => "396"
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need help to subtract?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. Please also note that [so] is not a coding service. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Comment: Take a look at the PHP function [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Or just use a plain [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(309=>"100",310=>"200",311=>"400");
$arr2 = array(309=>"1",310=>"2",311=>"4");

$out = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k => $v){
    // Since you need quote so, otherwise no need
    $out[$k] = '"'.($v - $arr2[$k]).'"';
}
print_r($out);

?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [309] => "99"
    [310] => "198"
    [311] => "396"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$a1=array("309"=>"100","310"=>"200","311"=>"400");
$a2=array("309"=>"1","310"=>"2","311"=>"4");
$res = array();
foreach ($a1 as $key => $value) {

   $res[$key] = $a1[$key]-$a2[$key];
}


print_r($res);
?>
```

**Output**

```
 Array ( 
    [309] => "99"
    [310] => "198"
    [311] => "396"
    )
```